# Failure to bind to forwarding reference

Tags: c++

I have a function `merge_and_sort`

```
template<template<typename, typename...> typename Container1, template<typename, typename...> typename Container2, typename T, typename U, typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
auto merge_and_sort(Container1<T, Args1...>&& first, Container2<U, Args2...>&& second)
{
  std::remove_reference_t<Container1<std::common_type_t<T, U>>> result(first.size() + second.size());
  std::merge(first.begin(), first.end(), second.begin(), second.end(), result.begin());
  std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
  return result;
}
```

However, when I call it with `merge_and_sort(foo, bar)`, where foo is a vector of ints, and bar is a vector of floats (ignore the fact that the result type is always Container1, should be a non issue), I get and error:

```
Error C2664 'auto merge_and_sort<std::vector,std::vector,float,int,std::allocator<_Ty>,std::allocator<int>>(std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &&,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<float,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'std::vector<float,std::allocator<_Ty>> &&'
```

Could someone point me to why this happens? Also, I am not looking for an alternate way to do this, rather a solution to why this happens. The code works perfectly fine when the parameters are lvalue references.

Comment: Are you sure it's a forwarding reference? I think you have a regular rvalue reference

Answer (score 2):

Your parameters `ContainerN<T, ArgsN...>&&` are not forwarding references, but rather actual rvalue references.

This is basically by definition, since `ContainerN<T, ArgsN...>` is not a template parameter:

> A forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter that does not represent a template parameter of a class template (during class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])).

http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#3.sentence-3